# Geospatial search in Lucene 3.0.3 - API Breaking chages?

Tags: c#, search, lucene.net, geospatial

I am trying to implement a geospatial search in the latest version on Lucene.NET (3.0.3).

I have installed Lucene.Net (3.0.3), Lucene.Net Contrib (3.0.3) and Lucene.Net Contrib Spacial (3.0.3).

I was using this excellent example to get a simple spacial search working.

http://www.leapinggorilla.com/blog/Read/1010/spatial-search-in-lucenenet---worked-example

It includes the following line:

```
IProjector projector = new SinusoidalProjector();
var ctp = new CartesianTierPlotter(0, projector, Fields.LocationTierPrefix);
```

The classes / interfaces IProjector, SinusoidalProjector and CartesianTierPlotter cannot be found.

From the docs they look like they should be located here.

Lucene.Net.Spatial.Tier

However this entire namespace is missing.

Can some one examplain how to get the above example working in the latest version of lucene and how the api has changed regarding these classes in the latest release?

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio. did you add assemblies to your project after you installed it? It is possible that VS or what ever tool you are using just can't find the `dll` libraries to give you that name space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I joined the lucene.net mailing list and put the question over to the experts. I've included the response from Itamar Syn-Hershko below.

> Yes, Lucene.NET 3.0.3 is using a different spatial search module,
>   based on spatial4n / spatial4j
>
> I will have a blog post up soon to describe how to work. Here's some
>   write up I did a while ago on that:
>   http://code972.com/blog/2012/05/51-the-future-of-geo-spatial-searches-with-lucene,